# Comparing every element in a list with each other and printing a pattern

Tags: arrays, python-3.7

I defined a list :

```
my_list = [1,34,56,78,97,889]
```

Each element should be compared and have printed its left least value.

For example: comparing 1 and 34, 1 is less than 34, so append into a new list and so on until the last element in the list.

My code is:

```
lio = [1,34,56,78,97,889]
i = 0
liu = []
while i <= len(lio) - 1: 
    if lio[i] < (lio[i + 1]) - 1:
        liu.append(lio[i])
        print(liu)
    i = i + 1
```

When I run it, it prints until 97, after that it shows list index out of range.

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate`

**Ex:**

```
lio = [1,34,56,78,97,889]
i = 0
liu = []
l = len(lio)
for i, v in enumerate(lio):
    if i+1 == l:              #Check if end of list
        continue              #Skip processing 

    if v < (lio[i + 1]):
        liu.append(v)
        print(liu)
    i = i + 1
```